# Coloring a line of a table

Tags: tables, colortbl, makecell

I try to color only the first line of the table below, using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\mygray}{\cellcolor{gray}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
 \begin{center}
    \setcellgapes{5pt} \makegapedcells \setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|x{1cm}|x{4cm}|x{4cm}|}\hline
      \mygray &\mygray 1 & \mygray 1 \\ \hline
      1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
      1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
 \end{center}
\end{table}
```

The output is [image]

I don't know where am I wrong?

Comment: What happens without the makegapedcells command?

Comment: I used \makegapedcells for vertical centering of the cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`makegepedcells`from the `makecell` package seems to interfere with colored cells. As an alternative, you can use the `cellspace` package. In the following MWE, I have also replaced your `x` type column with `wc` from the `array` package as well as the repeated `\cellcolor` commands with a single `\rowcolor`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{x}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
 \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|0{wc{1cm}}|0{wc{4cm}}|0{wc{4cm}}|}\hline
      \rowcolor{gray} & 1 &  1 \\ \hline
      1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
      1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to compile the MWE, but the following error occurs: '! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (w): `c' used.'

Comment: @Cris: Do you have a recent version of the  array package?

Comment: @Bernard No, I don't think. How can I update it?

Comment: With the package manager. Which distribution do you have?

Comment: I solved it. Thank you !

Comment: @leandriis Thank you very much ! Your alternative is much simpler and works well.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit=5pt,cell-space-bottom-limit=5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
 \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{wc{1cm}|wc{4cm}|wc{4cm}|}[hvlines,code-before=\rowcolor{gray}{1}]
        & 1 & 1 \\ 
      1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
      1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You can acheive the desired result with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` with the following avantages:

- You won't have the top rule vanishing in the PDF viewers at some level of zoom.
- You don't have to prefix each column of the preamble with a prefix of `cellspace` since you have global options `cell-space-top-limit` and `cell-space-bottom-limit` doing the job.
- You can draw all the required rules with only one key `hvlines`.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I succeeded to install and update the 'nicematrix' package. It's interesting, I try to get used to it. Thank you!